# Accuracy estimator for scan sample of categorical time series

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, unbiased-estimator, association-measure

Suppose we are tracking the behavior of some agent over time, and this agent can only exist in two states (+, -). This agent is only active for 20 timesteps, but we are only able to observe the agent for 5 sequential timesteps. The scan sample we take of the agent's behavior is denoted by | | in the following time series:

++++---|++-+-|-++----+

Drawing from time series in this way results in the following count data:

|  | + | - |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full Dataset | 10 | 10 |
| Sample Dataset | 3 | 2 |

To measure the degree of association between the sample and full time series, I was going to perform a chi-squared test and then derive Cramér's V. However, this procedure seems to violate at least two related assumptions of the chi-square test. 1) A subject can only contribute to only one cell of the contingency table. 2) Samples must be random, however sequential timesteps for the agent are autocorrelated. Is there a correction to the chi-square test I can implement to overcome these violations, or is there another unbiased estimator I can use to measure the similarity between the sample and the full dataset?

Citation for assumptions: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900058/

Comment: "Measure the degree of association" does not require any probability model.  You can adopt any measure appropriate for your application.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you! Are there any other measures that you would suggest? Ultimately I want to know if the true proportion of time the agent spends in each state is estimated well in the sample.